# sudo apt-get update command stopped?

Tags: 14.04, apt

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried all the given solutions related to this error and I am using Linux-14.04.2.iso on Oracle VM VirtualBox. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: When did you start getting this error

Comment: when I am running sudo apt-get update command after some steps it automatically showing above error.

Comment: What steps did you follow?

Comment: @Arun steps defined in this link    https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313394

Comment: There are two solutions in that link. Which one did you try? Or did you try both?

Comment: I stuck with first error only. It's keep popping up.. How to proceed any idea.